# How to select ${mapred.local.dir}?

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

If I configured several ${mapred.local.dir} directories to store immediate result of Map Task, these directories mounted different disks.
My questions are:
1. Whether `LocalDirAllocator.java` is used to manage ${mapred.local.dir} directories?

2.The method `getLocalPathForWrite()` of `LocalDirAllocator.java` is used to select a  ${mapred.local.dir} directory?

Comment: could you specify your purpose of managing this directory?

Comment: We want to use different disk(SDD and HDD) to run hadoop，in order to optimize hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Whether LocalDirAllocator.java is used to manage ${mapred.local.dir} directories?
```

Yes, the **tasktracker** uses `LocalDirAllocator` to manage the local directories/ disks inorder to store intermmediate data.(The by which it allocate space is given in the explanation)

```
2.The method getLocalPathForWrite() of LocalDirAllocator.java is used to select a ${mapred.local.dir} directory?
```

There are 3 overloaded methods in `LocalDirAllocator` corresponding to `getLocalPathForWrite()`.They round-robin over the set of disks (via the configured dirs) and return the first complete path which has enough space.

**Explantion** From the java doc: `LocalDirAllocator.java`

> An implementation of a round-robin scheme for disk allocation for
>   creating files. The way it works is that it is kept track what disk
>   was last allocated for a file write. For the current request, the next
>   disk from the set of disks would be allocated if the free space on the
>   disk is sufficient enough to accommodate the file that is being
>   considered for creation. If the space requirements cannot be met, the
>   next disk in order would be tried and so on till a disk is found with
>   sufficient capacity. Once a disk with sufficient space is identified,
>   a check is done to make sure that the disk is writable. Also, there is
>   an API provided that doesn't take the space requirements into
>   consideration but just checks whether the disk under consideration is
>   writable (this should be used for cases where the file size is not
>   known apriori). An API is provided to read a path that was created
>   earlier. That API works by doing a scan of all the disks for the input
>   pathname. This implementation also provides the functionality of
>   having multiple allocators per JVM (one for each unique functionality
>   or context, like mapred, dfs-client, etc.). It ensures that there is
>   only one instance of an allocator per context per JVM.

**Note:**

> 1. The contexts referred above are actually the configuration items defined in the Configuration class like "mapred.local.dir" (for which
>      we want to control the dir allocations). The context-strings are
>      exactly those configuration items.
> 2. This implementation does not take into consideration cases where a disk becomes read-only or goes out of space while a file is being
>      written to (disks are shared between multiple processes, and so the
>      latter situation is probable).
>
>    3. In the class implementation, "Disk" is referred to as "Dir", which actually points to the configured directory on the Disk which will be
>         the parent for all file write/read allocations.

I don't think we can directly override its behaviour, unless we override behaviour of its dependents!

Comment: Thank you for your help,I want to ask what's the means of 'behaviour of its dependents'?

Comment: I mean the taskcontroller , tasktracker etc.